# How to read rows count using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I came across a stored procedure that is returning number of rows but am not sure how can I read number of rows here,

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Document_Exists]
(
    @Url varchar(255)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows 
    FROM Document_Instances 
    WHERE Url = @Url
```

Executed as

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[Document_Exists]
     @SourceSiteUrl = N'https://cc23.dev.com/portal'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

trying to read it with this code

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Document_Exists", conn);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Url", url));
SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr1.Read())
{
```

dunno what to do next

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use a reader for this? It can be done with the sql command and an output parameter instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
int rows = 0;
if(rdr1.Read()) {
    rows = (int) rdr1["Rows"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Where is the point to use SqlDataReader when you return a single value from your proc?

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Document_Exists", conn); 
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Url", url)); 
int rows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalRows=0;
if(rdr1.Read())
{
    totalRows=  rdr1.GetInt32(rdr1.GetOrdinal("Rows"));
}
```

If you are retuning only a single value, I recommend you to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
int rowCount = dataReader.Cast<object>().Count();
```